# Why unresolved reference error thrown with while loop, whereas for for loop worked fine in kotlin

Tags: kotlin

Just encountered a problem while working with kotlin. check below code example. The below code executes with out compilation error. **But initially I had while in place of for loop** in below code. and that was throwing unresolved reference error to element.

Why are we having such weird and unexpected behaviour in Kotlin.Just started out with kotlin please excuse.

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
  /* Enter your code here. Read input from STDIN. Print output to STDOUT */
  val myarr=intArrayOf(1,2,3,4)

  for(element in myarr){
      println(element)
  }
```

}
Below is code for which i am having an error. My question is why is it working for for loop and not for while

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
  /* Enter your code here. Read input from STDIN. Print output to STDOUT */
  val myarr=intArrayOf(1,2,3,4)

  while(element in myarr){
      println(element)
  }
```

}

Comment: You would have to show the `while` code. Did you ever define `element`?

Comment: We can't help unless you post the while loop to see what's different or possibly causing a problem,

Comment: The `while` loop doesn't support the `in` syntax. To achieve what you need, use the `for` loop.

Comment: @Carcigenicate element is not defined in for loop code too above but it worked, why not in while

Comment: It is defined in the `for` when you wrote `for(element...`.

Comment: @NaseerMohammad I'd assume the downvote was for asking about code you didn't show. In general it's best not to imagine reasons for why people downvote, or assume they're ignorant because they downvoted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not good to use `in` in while loop. However you can do something like below:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    var i = 0
    val myarr=intArrayOf(1,2,3,4)
    while (i < myarr.size)
        println(myarr[i++])
}
```

Ref:
http://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/control-flow.html#while-loops

Answer (score 4):

`while` loops require a boolean argument. `in` isn't a iterator in this case, it's equivalent to the `in` boolean check. Example:

```
fun demo(){
    val x = 2;
    val l = listOf(1, 2, 3);
    while(x in l){

    }
}
```

Note that this is horrible code and it will cause an infinite loop. But it does show you the point; in a while loop, `in` is for booleans, and not a range. This also applies to arrays.

The reason it's an unresolved reference is because you are doing a boolean check, and not a for loop. For loops auto-declare the field, where as a `while`, but also `if` requires an existing field (i.e. `val x = something`), or a direct declaration (i.e. `while (2 in l)`). The latter removes the variable name.

So `while` loops don't take iterables like `for`. You have five options for iterating through an iterable:

1. `for(i in 0 until list.size)` - `list.size` can be any call, as long as it's an int
2. `for (item in list)` - this requires list to be an iterable.
3. ```
   var i = 0;
   while(i < list.size) {
       // remember to increment `i`, otherwise it's an infinite loop
   }
   ```
4. `list.forEach { }` and `list.forEachIndexed { i, item -> TODO() }`
5. I do not recommend this, since there are better options using the Kotlin stdlib, but it's still an option: `list.stream().forEach({ item -> TODO() })`

---

If you CTRL+click in IntelliJ on `in` in the while loop, you'll get redirected to `override fun contains(element: @UnsafeVariance E): Boolean`. As you see, this method returns a boolean. If you do the same in a for loop, you'll get redirected to `override fun iterator(): Iterator<E>`. As you see, these have two very different return types. The `while` loop uses the boolean one, and a `for` loop would use the iterator one. `in` is merely syntactical in this case.

And to end this, I highly recommend you use for loops, especially since you have an array. There's nothing wrong with a while loop though, using `for` is a personal preference.

---

And to close off what I said, the reason you get an unresolved reference is because the while loop doesn't actually declare a variable. If you add a variable, your code would compile, but it would be an infinite loop if the item is in the array:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
  val myarr=intArrayOf(1,2,3,4)
  var element = 0; //if this is in the list, the the while loop is an infinite loop.
  while(element in myarr){
      println(element)
  }

}
```